# Touchpad scrolling on one page applies to other pages

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, scrolling

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Lets say I have two windows open, a Chrome tab and a text editor.The chrome window is on top of the text editor.

If I scroll all the way down on the chrome page and ALT + TAB to my text editor, now the view position from the Chrome window is applied to my editor window.

Has anyone else experienced this on Ubuntu? What is the solution?

**EDIT :**

It looks like this may be related to the following:
https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.10.4/touchpad_jumping_cursor.html

Comment: Same thing happens with external mouse, doesn't seem to be limited to any particular software

Comment: No 1 else experiences this ??